# Separate PDF into pages and name each one with extracted text

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a big pdf with student data. Each page is a single report for a different student. All reports have the same format.

I want to separate each page and name it with the student's name and ID from that page.

I'm using Python and PyPDF2 and pdfplumber. I don't really know Python, but I'm piecing together pieces of code and I think I'm almost there.

The code I have now only works with a single page pdf. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
import pdfplumber


def pdf_splitter(path):

#separate pages with PyPDF2
        pdf = PdfReader(path)
        for page in range(len(pdf.pages)):
            pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
            pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[page])
        
#get filename with pdfplumber
        with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
            first_page = pdf.pages[0]
            txt = (first_page.extract_text()).split()
         
            lname = txt[txt.index('Student:')+1]
            lname = lname[:-1]
            fname = txt[txt.index('Student:')+2]
            id = txt[txt.index('ID:')+1]
            
            output_filename = '{} - {} - {}.pdf'.format(lname, fname, id)
        

        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)

        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))

        
#update path with file 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'file.pdf'
    pdf_splitter(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that PyPDF2 can do everything I needed. I didn't need to use pdfplumber at all. I think I was having trouble with the logic of combining them.

My pdf is really simple since every page is a new report with the same format. Here's my working code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

#update with file 
pdf_file = open('file','rb')
pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)


pageNumbers = len(pdf_reader.pages)

for i in range (pageNumbers):

    page = pdf_reader.pages[i]
    text = (page.extract_text()).split()

    id = text[-18]
    fname = text[-19]
    lname = text[-20]
    #trim the comma on the last name
    lname = lname[:-1]

    output_filename = '{} - {} - {}'.format(lname, fname, id)


    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[i])
    split_motive = open(output_filename + '.pdf','wb')
    pdf_writer.write(split_motive)
    split_motive.close()

pdf_file.close()
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing one problem comes from this

```
    pdf = PdfReader(path)
    for page in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        pdf_writer = PdfWriter()#This line is called each iteration, overwriting the already added data
        pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[page])
```

You could rewrite it as

```
    pdf = PdfReader(path)
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    for page in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[page])
```

But that alone won't necessarily get the functionality you're describing - I think you have to loop through and extract the information from every page

Try something like this

```
import pdfplumber
import os


def pdf_splitter(path):
    # Open the PDF file using pdfplumber
    with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
        # Iterate over each page
        for page in pdf.pages:
            # Extract the text from the page
            txt = page.extract_text().split()

            # Get the student's name and ID
            lname = txt[txt.index('Student:') + 1][:-1]
            fname = txt[txt.index('Student:') + 2]
            id = txt[txt.index('ID:') + 1]

            # Create the output filename
            output_filename = '{} - {} - {}.pdf'.format(lname, fname, id)

            # Write the page to the output file
            with pdfplumber.PDF(output_filename) as out_pdf:
                out_pdf.pages.append(page)
                out_pdf.save()

            print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))


# Update the path with the file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'file.pdf'
    pdf_splitter(path)
```